# Remove lines using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file like below. I would like to remove all lines before foo but leave just one last instance of bar.
Input:

```
bar1
foo
bar1
bar2
bar3
foo
bar5
bar6
bar7
foo
```

Output:

```
bar1
foo
bar3
foo
bar7
foo
```

Can someone please help me how to accomplish this. I'm trying to use sed but all my attempts gave nothing.

Comment: How do you have `bar6` in the desired output; shouldn't it be `bar7`?

Answer (score 6):

I hope it doesn't have to be `sed`. Use `grep`'s `-B` option to print the matching line and 1 line before it:

```
grep -B 1 foo input > output
```

Comment: `-A` if next line :) Good Answer

Comment: I believe OP wants `bar6` just before last `foo`.

Comment: @anubhava I'm willing to bet that was a typo in the example.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! That is exactly what I need:) I should have found this solution myself though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/^foo/ {print a "\n" $0} /^bar/ {a=$0}' file
bar1
foo
bar3
foo
bar7
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/^bar.*\nfoo/!D'  file
```